# @Cache annotation usage error

Tags: hibernate, caching, ejb-3.0, ehcache, java-ee-5

I added the following annotation to enable cache to one of my EJB3 entities, to test caching with ehCache, where I use Hibernate as the persistence provider:

```
....
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@Table(name = "F")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "F.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM F f")})
public class F implements Serializable {
   .....
}
```

I added the following to persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="/ehcache.xml"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
```

And when I try to compile I get the following error:

> /persistence/F.class): warning: Cannot
>   find annotation method 'usage()' in
>   type
>   'org.hibernate.annotations.Cache':
>   class file for
>   org.hibernate.annotations.Cache not
>   found An exception has occurred in the
>   compiler (1.6.0_16). Please file a bug
>   at the Java Developer Connection
>   (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)
>   after checking the Bug Parade for
>   duplicates. Include your program and
>   the following diagnostic in your
>   report. Thank you.
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure:
>   class file for
>   org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy
>   not found

Can anyone help me out here and let me know what I need to do or am doing wrong currently ?

Answer (score 4):

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Well .. I got it to work eventually. The fix for it is really strange and really does seem to be a reported bug.

What I needed to do was to add all the Hibernate libraries to my Netbeans web/war project as well. Once I did that, the errors went away.

This was strange because the Hibernate libraries were already included in the ear project which was also in the web project library.

Comment: Given that, you should accept your answer so that this question is closed.

Comment: Given that, you should also mention the missing dependencies in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong - your annotations are fine.

Judging by the error message it's a compiler bug. You can:

1. [Update to the latest JDK version](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) (1.6.0_16-b01).
2. Rearrange your annotations and hope that compiler bug will not be triggered. Yes, that sounds silly but I have used `@Cache` declarations extensively (as I'm sure many other people did) and I have no problems with compilation meaning you just got (un)lucky.
3. Try a different compiler (build from Eclipse)
4. Submit a bug report to Sun.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add hibernate-annotations jars to your web/war project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the hibernate libraries from **provided** to **compile** in the pom of a maven multi module project.