# Class file not found in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I get this weird error when I try to compile.

```
Cannot find annotation method 'cascade()' in type 'javax.persistence.ManyToOne': class file for javax.persistence.ManyToOne not found
```

I know, it seems pretty obvious what the problem is, but having spent too much time on this problem I now turn my trust to you!

I use ideaCommunity-9, where I have created a global library for JBoss, which contains all JBoss jars including ejb3-persistence.jar. My module includes this library, and I have moved it to the top of dependencies.
No otherwhere in classpath I have a javax.persistence.ManyToOne class, and it also opens up in IntelliJ without problems.
If I open the file where I get the compile error, IntelliJ shows no problems and also navigates to the class file on pressing Ctrl+B.
The code is also build with ant and here it works fine.

Besides the above error I get six others along the same path (name in Table, etc.) - all related to JPA. I also get a message saying "Please file a bug to JDC yada yada yada."

Comment: Can you open the class 'ManyToOne' using keyboard shortcut <Ctrl>+N?

Comment: Yes I have no problem viewing the class file for ManyToOne. It gives me a location in ejb3-persistence.jar which again is located within JBoss.  It also has the method cascade().

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to tick a checkbox "export" in your dependencies.

I mean: "File" menu -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies, and there you can see libs included to the module. You should also see a checkbox near each lib in column 'Export'.

Comment: I had a similar issue (different annotation same error). This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes an Intellij restart might be needed after this.

Comment: This doesn't worked for me. Instead Build -> Rebuild Project worked

Answer (score 14):

Just got this myself but non of those things were my issue. I downloaded a project from github, then opened in intelli J with the problem after trying to run a junit test.

Solution: Project Structure -> Modules -> 'Project_Name' -> Sources (tab) -> click src folder -> Mark as: Sources

This should highlight src to be blue and all the class files should be the circles with C instead of looking like normal files. Try running a test again and see if that does it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure, it is too late to answer, but I had to follow a different approach for this error to resolve this issue.

I had to create this as global library and add that library to the module, then only the error is resolved.

[image: Add this as a global library]

[image: Then add that library as dependency to the project]

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613952/cache-annotation-usage-error)?

The solution there was to add all JBoss jar (which you did), but also all persistent-related libraries (like Hibernate)

See this [JBoss project configuration](http://jdick.co.uk/blog/?p=83) for example:

[alt text http://jdick.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/projectstructure1.jpg](http://jdick.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/projectstructure1.jpg)

In short, `ejb3-persistence.jar` might not be the problem here, just a symptom of *other* elements missing.
Or, if it is the problem, it may be related to the fact that it is not deployed correctly (for the [WebApp configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/application_server.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:
Maybe you have multiple versions of your jar file.
Search your folder hierarchy for the file `ejb3-persistence.jar`,
using a file management tool such as Total Commander.
Multiple appearances of the file in your classpath may confuse IntelliJ Idea 
into not recognizing the proper class in the proper jar.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem ("cannot find class spring...DefaultResourceLoader even though it *was* in my maven dependencies) and no amount of tweaking of revalidating caches seemed to help.  Blowing away my $HOME/.Idea* paths and (basically) starting from scratch fixed it for me. At least for now...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `class not found` error message when trying to execute a `.groovy` test class, which referenced a `.groovy` file (located in the root of the source directory of a submodule - i.e. no packages).

Moving the source file `.groovy` into a package, fixed the issue for me.

*Move:*

```
src/main/groovy/RunMe.groovy
```

*to*

```
src/main/groovy/somePackage/RunMe.groovy
```

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ I got this problem when I built (ctrl+shift+F9) at the file level.

The reason is, I had changes in other files in the same maven project, that were not getting picked.

I solved it by building at the project level (Select the Maven project in intellij and press ctrl+shift+F9)